# Print all subsequence arrays where no elements are adjacents

Tags: java, algorithm

In the following i can able to print all the sub sequence arrays but can someone please help to print all the subsequence where no elements adjacent.

```
`package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test1 {
    public static List<List<Integer>> combinations(int[] arr) {
        List<List<Integer>> combinations = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        List<Integer> total;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int k = combinations.size();
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                // if ((i + 1 < arr.length)) {

                total = new ArrayList<Integer>(combinations.get(j));
                total.add(new Integer(arr[i]));

                combinations.add(total);
                // }
            }
            total = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            total.add(new Integer(arr[i]));
            combinations.add(total);
        }
        System.out.println(combinations);
        return combinations;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
        combinations(arr);
    }
}`
```

output :- [[1], [1, 2], [2], [1, 3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3]]

expected output : - [[1], [2], [1, 3],[3]]

Comment: Seems question about java. Better to remove tags `c` and `groovy`

Comment: Given the array `[3, 1, 4, 1]`, would `[3, 1, 4, 1]` be a valid subsequence?

Comment: What is the expected output for `[1, 1]`, and why?

Comment: “where no elements adjacent” are we talking about the index of the element or the value?

Comment: @RolandIllig [[1],[1]] because it has only two elements

Comment: @Joakim Danielson we are considering index

Comment: Any reason why you haven't tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Generate Combinations:**

```
private static List<List<Integer>> generateCombinations(int[] arr){
        List<List<Integer>> combs = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        int prev2 = 1,prev1 = 1;
        
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;++i){
             //individual
            List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
            l.add(arr[i]);
            combs.add(l);   
            
            if(i < 2){ // since these are base cases for our fibonacci sequence
                continue;
            }
            
            int size = prev1 + prev2 - 1; 
            
            for(int j=0;j<size;++j){
                List<Integer> new_list = new ArrayList<>(combs.get(j));
                new_list.add(arr[i]);
                combs.add(new_list);
            }           
            
            prev1 = prev1 + prev2;
            prev2 = prev1 - prev2;
        }        
        
        return combs;
    }
```

**Driver Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
        List<List<Integer>> result = generateCombinations(arr);
        int size = result.size();
        for(int i=0;i<size;++i){
            System.out.println(result.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
[1, 3]
[4]
[1, 4]
[2, 4]
[5]
[1, 5]
[2, 5]
[3, 5]
[1, 3, 5]
```

**Algorithm:**

- Generating combinations avoiding adjacent elements actually follows a fibonacci sequence.

**Let's take array as as {1,2,3,4,5,6}**

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|                                                                         |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| Individual element's generated combinations excluding adjacent elements | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 8 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| Elements of the array                                                   | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

- In other words, this means that I would iterate all combinations from the start and stop at the point where it will be total combinations I could generate - 1(where `-1` is excluding for itself).
- Let's go through the combinations for better clarity. Assume, the first 2 combinations are already there.

> [1]
>
> [2]

- So, for `3` we would go from the start like,

> [1,3]
>
> [3] (this we would add ourselves)

- For `4`, we would have **all** combinations in front of us as:

> [1]
>
> [2]
>
> [1,3]
>
> [3]

- Now, we would only go till `[2]` and then stop, making combinations as:

> [1,4]
>
> [2,4]
>
> [4] (adding this ourselves).

- and so on so forth for upcoming elements. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to split the solution into two methods, one simple method that would create a List from the array for a given start position and step size and a main method that called the first one for all possible combinations.

```
static List<Integer> oneLoop(int[] arr, boolean isOdd, int step) {
    int start = isOdd ? 1 : 0;
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = start; i < arr.length; i += step) {
        result.add(arr[i]);    
    }
    return result;
}

static List<List<Integer>> combinations(int[] arr) {
    List<List<Integer>> allCombinations = new ArrayList<>();

    //Add each single element as separate list
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(arr[i]);
        allCombinations.add(list);
    }
    //Loop over an increasing larger step size until size is to large
    int step = 2;
    while (step < arr.length) {                        
        allCombinations.add(oneLoop(arr, false, step));
        if ( (step +1) < arr.length) {
            allCombinations.add(oneLoop(arr, true, step));
        }
        step += 1;
    }

    return allCombinations;
}
```

And this is my test method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[args.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        array[i] = Integer.valueOf(args[i]);
    } 
    List<List<Integer>> list = combinations(array);
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joakim   but for the input {1,2,3,4,5}   output : [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [1, 3, 5], [2, 4], [1, 4], [2, 5], [1, 5]]  which is correct but few sub-sequences are still not listed for eg:- [[1,3],[3,5]]

Comment: @loknath true, I thought about that scenario when designing this but then it must have slipped my mind when I wrote the code. The problem is that when a long answer exists, [1,3,5], the code must also check for shorter solutions within that longer answer